# removing NLTK StopWords

Tags: nlp, nltk, data-cleaning, stop-words

I am trying to remove stop words of my data set.

```
stopwordsw = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('german')

def remove_stopwords(txt_clean):
      txt_clean =  [Word for Word in txt_clean if Word not in stopwords]
      return txt_clean

data['Tweet_sw'] = data['Tweet_clean'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x))
data.head()
```

I have two problems with that.

First, the output is given character by character (separated by a comma), although I run the check against the list of stopwords with words.

I can solve this problem with a join command, but I don't understand why it is split into characters.

The second and real problem is that the removal of stop words does not work. Words that are clearly in the list are not removed from the sentences.

Where is my mistake in this?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv1kL.png)

Comment: can you try      `txt_clean =  [Word for Word in txt_clean.split()  if Word not in stopwords]`

Comment: Welcome :) The reason you were getting character output is because... You are iterating over a string (character by character) and putting it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

txt_clean =  [Word for Word in txt_clean.split()  if Word not in stopwords]